# What is wrong with Java's generics?

Tags: java, generics

I have seen several times on this site posts that decry Java's implementation of generics. Now, I can honestly say that I have not had any issues with using them. However, I have not attempted to make a generic class myself. So, what are your issues with Java's generic support?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355060/c-vs-java-generics

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31693/what-are-the-differences-between-generics-in-c-and-java-and-templates-in-c

Comment: as Clinton Begin (the "iBatis guy") said, ["they don't work..."](http://clintonbegin.blogspot.com/2008/02/clintons-java-5-rant.html)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Java's generic implementation uses [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure). This means that your strongly typed generic collections are actually of type `Object` at runtime. This has some performance considerations as it means primitive types must be boxed when added to a generic collection. Of course the benefits of compile time type correctness outweigh the general silliness of type erasure and obsessive focus on backwards compatibility.

Comment: Just to add, because of type erasure, retrieving generic information at runtime isn't possible unless you use something like a `TypeLiteral` http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html

Comment: Meaning that `new ArrayList<String>.getClass() == new ArrayList<Integer>.getClass()`

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence (or the second). If there are no compiler warnings, Java generics are sound at compile-time.

Comment: @Tom - Isn't that what I said?

Comment: Does C++ use type erasure?

Comment: @Job no it does not. And C++ uses a completelly different approach to metaprogramming called templates. It uses duck-typing and you can do useful things like `template<T> T add(T v1, T v2) { return v1->add(v2); }` and there you have a truly generic way of creating a function that `add` s two thing no matter what those things are, they just have to have a method named `add()` with one parameter.

Comment: @Trinidad, sounds like a fancy name for generated code :)

Comment: @Job it is generated code, indeed. Templates are meant to replace the C preprocessor and for doing so they should be able to make some very [clever tricks](http://aszt.inf.elte.hu/~gsd/halado_cpp/ch06s04.html) and are by themselves a Turing-complete language. Java generics are only sugar for type-safe containers, and C# generics are better but still a poor man's C++ template.

Comment: @Trinidad, thanks. I went to a http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/ThePerilsofJavaSchools.html and so I could not quite understand why hardcore C++ coders would diss Java and C# generics. Now I think I get it. As always, C++ lets you do just about anything even if you want to shoot yourself, while Java & .Net are trying to hold your hand. By the way, in what ways are C# generics better than those of Java?

Comment: @Job AFAIK, Java generics don't generate a class for each new generic type, it just adds typecasts to the code that uses generic methods, so it's not actually meta-programming IMO. C# templates do generate new code for each generic type, that is, if you use List<int> and List<double> in C#'s world would generate code for each of them. In comparison to templates, C# generics still require to know which type you can feed it You cannot implement the simple `Add` example I gave, there's no way without knowing beforehand which classes it can be applied to, which is a drawback.

Comment: That thing I said about generating code for each of them is what makes C# generics "without type erasure", each generic type is a new type. Also you're able to instantiate using generics, like ´ T GetInstanceOf<T>() where T : new() { return new T(); }; ´ and by calling ´ GetInstanceOf<Car> ´ will get you a new instance of a Car, but still notice that the compiler is not smart enough to tell _at compile-time and without reflection_ if the class you feed it has constructor with no parameters. In C++ the [ducks](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?DuckTyping) haz teh brainz ;)

Comment: -1 because while it is correct to say that Java uses type erasure, this answer is otherwise very misleading: Java generics *do* enforce compile time type correctness. Try adding an Integer to an ArrayList<String> - it won't compile. Certainly type erasure has disadvantages (reflection loses generic type information, extra runtime casts needed) and advantages (backward compatibility, performance benefit of only having to generate a single generic class and putting less pressure on the instruction cache) but cannot fairly be described as "general silliness" if you are being objective.

Comment: @mikera - *"Of course the benefits of compile time type correctness"*  I think you had a reading comprehension fail.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - not at all: the second sentence states that Java doesn't have doesn't have strongly typed collections (untrue at compile time), and in that context the third sentence is ambiguous at best. Please don't take the criticism personally as it is not intended that way, just improve the answer if you want more positive votes!

Comment: @mikera - I concede that my second sentence does seem a bit ambiguous. Hopefully my edits add some clarity.

Comment: Backward compatability is not silly.  It is what allows cathedrals to stand for centuries.

Comment: @user1249 You mean they would collapse in case the laws of physics change in a way that's not backwards compatible?

Comment: "but still notice that the compiler is not smart enough to tell at compile-time and without reflection if the class you feed it has constructor with no parameters."

Untrue. At compile time if you try to call GetInstanceOf<Widget> and widget doesn't have a parameterless constructor, you'll get an error.

Comment: _"Of course the benefits of compile time type correctness outweigh..."_ Your answer is perfect up until this point. You just had to go ahead and make it political... :(

Answer (score 28):

Observe that answers that have already been provided concentrate on the combination of Java-the-language, JVM and the Java Class Library.

There is nothing wrong with Java's generics as far as Java-the-language is concerned. As described in [C# vs Java generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355060/c-vs-java-generics), Java's generics are pretty much fine on the language level<sup>1</sup>.

What's suboptimal is that the JVM doesn't support generics directly, which has several major consequences:

- the reflection-related parts of the Class Library can't expose the full type information that was available in Java-the-language
- some performance penalty is involved

I suppose the distinction I am making is a pedantic one as Java-the-language is ubiquitously compiled with JVM as the target and Java Class Library as the core library.

<sup>1</sup> With the possible exception of wildcards, which is believed to make the type inference undecidable in the general case. This is a major difference between C# and Java generics that isn't mentioned very often at all. Thanks, Antimony.

Comment: The JVM does not need to support generics. This would be the same as saying that C++ has no templates because the ix86 real machine does not support templates, which is false. The problem is the approach the compiler takes to implement generic types. And again, C++ templates involve no penalty at run-time, there's no reflection being done at all, I guess the only reason that would be need to be done in Java is just poor language design.

Comment: @Trinidad but I did not say Java doesn't have generics, so I don't see how it's the same. And yeah, the JVM does not **need** to support them, just like C++ does not **need** to optimize the code. But not optimizing it would certainly count as "something wrong".

Comment: What I argued is that there's no need for the JVM to have direct support for generics for being able to use reflection on them. Others have done it so it can be done, the problem is that Java does not generate new classes from generics, the no reification thing.

Comment: @Trinidad, the reason Java generics aren't reified is that they were added later and backwards compatibility was desired. (Same reason that C#'s generics have some problems).

Comment: What I can't understand is why Java (and C#) chose to not implement generics (or templates) in the first place.

Comment: @mathepic I'd guess to cut down the amount of work on v1, possibly... I fully agree though, as do [a lot of other people](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2815/what-would-you-change-about-c-if-you-could/6135#6135)

Comment: I don't think this has as much to do with a desire for backwards compatibility as it was "look this guy implemented generic support with the limitations of our existing runtime, instead of taking the effort to bake it in like we should, let's just use his code and call it done."

Comment: @Trinidad: In C++, assuming the compiler given enough time and memory, templates can be used to do anything and everything that can be done with information that is available at compile time (since compilation of templates is Turing-complete), but there is no way to create templates using information which is not available before the program is run.  In .net, by contrast, it is possible for a program to create types based upon input; it would be fairly easy to write a program where the number of different types that could be created exceeds the number of electrons in the universe.

Comment: @Trinidad: Obviously, no single execution of the program could create all of those types (or, indeed, anything beyond an infinitesimal fraction of them), but the point is it doesn't have to.  It only needs to create types which are actually used.  One could have a program which could accept any arbitrary number (e.g. `8675309`) and from it create a type unique to that number (e.g. `Z8<Z6<Z7<Z5<Z3<Z0<Z9>>>>>>>`), which would have different members from any other type.  In C++, all types that could be generated from any input would have to be produced at compile time.

Comment: @romkyns Actually there are problems with generics at the language level. Among other things, they're complex and hard to understand once you get into the details. Generic subtyping is thought to be undeciable. Some complicated generics will cause the compiler to crash.

Comment: @Timwi http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~atl017/papers/pldi11.pdf  The paper appears to be talking about Java 6, so I don't know whether they've fixed things since. But at the very least, it does show the complexities involved in the type system.

Answer (score 13):

The usual criticism is the lack of reification. That is to say objects at runtime do not contain information about their generic arguments (although the information is still present on fields, method, constructors and extended class and interfaces). This means that you could cast, say, `ArrayList<String>` to `List<File>`. The compiler will give you warnings, but it will also warn you if you take an `ArrayList<String>` assign it to an `Object` reference and then cast it to `List<String>`. The upsides are that with generics you probably shouldn't be doing the casting, performance is better without the unnecessary data and, of course, backward compatibility.

Some people complain that you cannot overload on the basis of generic arguments (`void fn(Set<String>)` and `void fn(Set<File>)`). You need to use better method names instead. Note that this overloading would not require reification, as overloading is a static, compile-time issue.

Primitive types don't work with generics.

Wildcards and bounds are quite complicated. They are very useful. If Java preferred immutability and tell-don't-ask interfaces, then declaration-side rather than use-side generics would be more appropriate.

Comment: "Note that this overloading would not require reification, as overloading is a static, compile-time issue." Wouldn't it? How would it work without reification? Wouldn't the JVM have to know at runtime which type of set you have, in order to know which method to call?

Comment: @MatrixFrog No. As I say, overloading is a compile-time issue. The compiler uses the static type of the expression to select a particular overload, which is then the method written to the class file. If you have `Object cs = new char[] { 'H', 'i' }; System.out.println(cs);` you get nonsense printed. Change the type of `cs` to `char[]` and you'll get `Hi`.

Answer (score 10):

Java generics suck because you can't do the following:

```
public class AsyncAdapter<Parser,Adapter> extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Adapter> {
    proptected Adapter doInBackground(String... keywords) {
      Parser p = new Parser(keywords[0]); // this is an error
      /* some more stuff I was hoping for but couldn't do because
         the compiler wouldn't let me
      */
    }
}
```

You wouldn't need to butcher every class in the above code to get it to work as it should if generics were actually generic class parameters.

Comment: You don't need to butcher every class. You just need to add a suitable factory class and inject it into AsyncAdapter. (And fundamentally this isn't about generics, but the fact that constructors aren't inherited in Java).

Comment: @PeterTaylor: A suitable factory class just shoves all the boilerplate into some other out of sight mess and it still doesn't solve the problem. Now every time I want to instantiate a new instance of `Parser` I'll need to make the factory code even more convoluted. Whereas if "generic" truly meant generic then there would be no need for factories and all the other nonsense that goes by the name of design patterns. It's one of the many reasons I prefer to work in dynamic languages.

Comment: Sometimes similar in C++, where you can't pass the address of a constructor, when using templates+virtuals - you can just use a factory functor instead.

Comment: Java sucks because you can't write "proptected" before a name of a method? Poor you. Stick to dynamic languages. And be especially wary of Haskell.

Answer (score 5):

I think other answers have said this to some degree, but not very clearly.  One of the problems with generics is losing the generic types during the reflection process.  So for example:

```
List<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
assertTrue( ArrayList.class, arr.getClass() );
TypeVarible[] types = arr.getClass().getTypedVariables();
```

Unfortunately, the returned types can't tell you that arr's generic types are String.  It's a subtle difference, but it's important.  Because arr is created at runtime the generic types are erased at runtime so you can't figure that out.  As some stated `ArrayList<Integer>` looks the same as `ArrayList<String>` from a reflection standpoint.

This might not matter to the user of Generics, but let's say we wanted to create some fancy framework that used reflection to figure out fancy things about how the user declared an instance's concrete generic types.

```
Factory<MySpecialObject> factory = new Factory<MySpecialObject>();
MySpecialObject obj = factory.create();
```

Let's say we wanted a generic factory to create an instance of `MySpecialObject` because that's the concrete generic type we declared for this instance.  Well Factory class can't interrogate itself to find out the concrete type declared for this instance because Java erased them.

In .Net's generics you can do this because at runtime the object knows it's generic types because the compiler complied it into the binary.  With erasures Java can't do this.

Answer (score 5):

- compiler warnings for missing generic parameters that serve no purpose make the language pointlessly verbose, e.g   `public String getName(Class<?> klazz){ return klazz.getName();}`
- Generics [don't play nice with arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470198/java-generics-and-array-initialization)
- Lost type information makes reflection a mess of casting and duct tape.

Comment: I do get annoyed when I get a warning for using `HashMap` instead of `HashMap<String, String>`.

Comment: @Michael but that actually _should_ be used with generics...

Comment: The array problem goes to reifiability.  See the Java Generics book (Alligator) for an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I could say a few *good* things about generics, but that wasn't the question.  I could complain that they're not available at run time and don't work with arrays, but that's been mentioned.

*A big psychological annoyance:*  I occasionally get into situations where generics cannot be made to work.  (Arrays being the simplest example.)  And I cannot figure out whether generics can't do the job or whether I'm just stupid.  *I hate that.*  Something like generics ought to work always.  Every other time I can't do what I want using Java-the-language, I *know* the problem is me, and I know if I just keep pushing, I'll get there eventually.  With generics, if I become too persistent, I can waste a lot of time.

**But the real problem** is that generics add too much complexity for too little gain.  In the simplest cases it can stop me from adding an apple to a list containing cars.  Fine.  But without generics this error would throw a ClassCastException really quick at run time with little time wasted.  If I add a car with a child seat with a child in it, do I need a compile-time warning that the list is only for cars with child seats that contain baby chimpanzees?  A list of plain Object instances starts to look like a good idea.

Generic'ed code can have a lot of words and characters and take up a lot of extra space and take a lot longer to read.  I can spend a lot of time getting all that extra code to work right.  When it does, I feel insanely clever.  I've also wasted several hours or more of my own time and I have to wonder if anyone else is ever going to be able to figure out the code.  I'd like to be able to hand it off for maintenance to people who are either less smart than myself or who have less time to waste.

*On the other hand* (I got a bit wound up there and feel a need to provide some balance), it is nice when using simple collections and maps to have adds, puts, and gets checked when written, and it usually does not add much complexity to the code *(****if*** *someone* ***else*** *writes the collection or map)*.  And Java is better at this than C#.  It seems none of the C# collections I want to use ever handle generics.  (I admit I have strange tastes in collections.)

Comment: Nice rant. However, there are many libraries/frameworks which could exists without generics, e.g., Guice, Gson, Hibernate. And generics are not that hard once you get used to it. Typing and reading the type arguments is a real PITA; here [val](http://projectlombok.org/features/val.html) helps if you can use.

Comment: @maaartinus: Wrote that a while ago. Also OP did ask for "issues". I find generics extremely useful and like them a lot--much more now than then. However, __if__ you are writing your own collection, they are very hard to learn. And their usefulness fades when your collection's type is determined at run time--when the collection has a method _telling_ you the class of its entries. At this point generics don't work and your IDE will produce hundreds of meaningless warnings. 99.99% of Java programming doesn't involve this. But I'd _just_ had a __lot__ of trouble with this when I wrote the above.

Comment: Being both Java and C# developer, I am wondering why would you prefer Java collections?

Comment: `Fine. But without generics this error would throw a ClassCastException really quick at run time with little time wasted.` That really depends on how much run time occurs between program startup and hitting the line of code in question.  If a user reports the error and it takes you several minutes (or, worst-case scenario, hours or even days) to reproduce, that compile-time verification starts looking better and better...